# Regex in Ruby not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex

I have a string from which I want to extract a certain part:

Original String: `/abc/d7_t/g-12/jkl/m-n3/pqr/stu/vwx`

Result Desired: `/abc/d7_t/g-12/jkl/`

The number of characters can vary in the entire string. It has alphabets, numbers, underscore and hyphen. I want to basically cut the string after the 5th "/"

I tried a few regex, but it seems there is some mistake with the format.

Comment: http://rubular.com is your friend

Comment: So what's the rule you want to apply? Always cut before `pqr`? Or after the 6th instance of `/`? Or the 16th character? Or the 4th digit? What? Clarify this and you'll be halfway there...

Comment: I did something like this : (/[wW]/[wW]/[wW]/[wW]/[wW]/)....I m not sure how to find a "/" and also w & W doesn't include the symbol '-' which is present in my string at many places

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisCorbett : The number of characters can vary. I want to cut the string after the 5th "/"

Comment: "I tried a few regex.." where is your sample?.

Comment: Why not just split it with `/` and join the first 5 parts with `/` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If a non-regexp approach is acceptable, how about this:

```
s.split('/').take(n).join('/')+'/'
```

Where `s` if your string (in your case: `/abc/d7_t/g-12/jkl/m-n3/pqr/stu/vwx`).

```
def cut_after(s, n)
  s.split('/').take(n).join('/')+'/'
end
```

Then

```
cut_after("/abc/d7_t/g-12/jkl/m-n3/pqr/stu/vwx", 5)
```

should work. Not as compact as a regexp, but some people may find it clearer.

Comment: That's *fine* if you hate regexes - making it clear that a *non-regex* solutions are also acceptable would be useful(people, including myself, love to find a regexp fix to solutions with the goal of doing it in regexps  ;-))

Answer (score 2):

The regexp would be: `%r(/(?:[^/]+/){4})`. Note that it is a good idea in this case to use the %r literal version to avoid escaping slashes. Unescaped slashes are likely the cause of your format errors.

Comment: Please note my comment as well. It's the 6th slash he wants (he forgot to include the first in the count).

Comment: Looks like 5 slashes to me. I just double counted. Also, before I posted I checked my result in irb against his desired result.

Comment: wow, my bad, I must have had an error in my original Regex I tested. -.-

Answer (score 1):

Match any sequence of chars except '/' 4 times :-

```
(\/[^\/]+){4}\/
```